# Law of Demeter vs. REST

Tags: rest, law-of-demeter

The Law of Demeter (really should be the suggestion of Demeter) says that you shouldn't "reach through" an object to get at their child objects.  If you, as a client, need to perform some non-trivial operation, most of the time the domain model you're working with should support that operation.

REST is in principle a dumb hierarchy of objects.  It is like a filesystem of resources/objects, where each object could have child objects.  You almost always reach through with REST.  You can optionally build up by-convention composite object types using REST techniques, and as long as the provider and the client agree on higher-level operations, you can avoid the reach-through.

So, how do you balance REST and Demeter?  It seems to me that they are not in conflict, because REST is all about super-loose coupling to the point where it is pointless for the provider to try to anticipate all the needs of the clients, whereas Demeter assumes that logic can migrate to its most natural place through refactoring.

However, you could argue that REST is just a stop-gap until you understand your clients better.  Is REST just a hack?  Is Demeter unrealistic in any server/client scenario?

Comment: This is an apples and oranges comparison.  REST is about building scalable distributed systems using a uniform interface.  The Law of Demeter is about reducing coupling between parts of a system.

Comment: Are you thinking of a situation where the client constructs a URL for a child object instead of having the child URL handed to it? That would be a violation, I think, but not if the URL is the result of a parent operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Is Demeter unrealistic in any server/client scenario?

I think you answered your own question here. How is `REST` in this manner different than `SOAP` or `XML-RPC` in this regard?

The point of `REST` is not to provide super-loose coupling, but the following:

- Provide a identifier which accurately describes the resource being requested.
- Provide services which behave as expected `GET` requests are idempotent, `PUT` updates records, `POST` creates, `DELETE` deletes
- Minimize state being stored on the server
- Tear down unnecessary complexity

There are cases where `REST` isn't the best answer, but `REST` works remarkably well in general.

Comment: I mean REST in the sense of any URL-based object access mechanism.  A URL is a violation of Demeter.

Comment: All good points, thanks.  I guess I was thinking of "deep" REST hierarchies.  Not all REST needs to be that way, but I work on a project that uses a URI-based model for a loosely-coupled system and I'm concerned that a deep hierarchy can be used to avoid understanding clients' needs better.

Answer (score 2):

I pay that law/suggestion no mind whatsoever.  It defeats half the benefit of aggregation and composition, and I won't have it.

Comment: In fact,  IMAO it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far.  If you're really getting at the classes private parts, it makes the system more brittle.  that doesn't mean you cant have methods in the signature of the class that just call methods on the aggregated class.

Answer (score 2):

A link that is provided by a representation, exposed by a RESTful interface, can be completely opaque without violating any of REST's constraints.  Therefore I would suggest that REST is completely consistent with the Law of Demeter.  There is no requirement that the link expose the structure of the URL space in its URL.

e.g. in an object oriented scenario, you might replace the call a.b.c with a.bc

In a RESTful representation you could create the following:

```
<a>
  <link href="bc"/>
</a>
```

instead of doing

```
GET a

    <a>
      <link href="b"/>
    </a>

GET b

    <b>
      <link href="c"/>
    </b>

GET c
```

I would have to disagree with altCognito and say that one of the main goals of REST is loose coupling.  The uniform interface, standard media types and HATEOAS all combine to produce an extremely loosely coupled interface.

In response to David's comment:

> REST is all about super-loose coupling to the point where it is pointless for the provider to try to anticipate all the needs of the clients

Actually, REST is about limiting the clients options by providing only valid links in the representations.  Within those constraints the client can attempt to satisfy its own needs.  It is by removing the knowledge from the client of when certain requests can be made that you achieve loose coupling.  Loose coupling is not achieved by listing a set of resources and saying "ok, you can GET, PUT, POST, DELETE all you want."

Answer (score 1):

I think they're really orthogonal.  REST describes a collection of resources addressed by URIs with a set of canonical methods: GET, POST, etc.  If  REST routine returns a URI, that's not "reaching through" it's identifying a different object with the same method names.